# Break points on User Defined object properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, debugging, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

Break points on User Defined object properties in javascript

Hello

Is there is any JavaScript debugging tool or addon that helps to put break points on 
User Defined object properties.

Eg:

I have a JavaScript Object Literal

`var TextBox = {
    color:"gray",
    size:"100px",
    border:true 
}`

Here is my code that does the modification

`function foo(){
    TextBox["color"] = "blue";
}`

I am looking for putting a breakpoint on **TextBox.color** so that when the property is modified I could find
who is doing the modification or which function does the alteration.

It should also break when 

`TextBox.color = null;
or
delete TextBox.color;`

Is this feature already available in firebug or chrome developer tool?

I have already seen breakpoints for html element removal , attribute modification 
but not for **user defined object properties**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the magic getters and setters that some browsers support:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters

You should be able to define a setter and put a breakpoint in it.

Probably best to keep these out of production code for compatibility reasons, but they're the only practical way to debug certain problems.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
(function() {
    var obj=TextBox; var realValue = obj.color; 
    Object.defineProperty(obj, 'color', { 
        set: function(newValue) { debugger; realValue = newValue; },
        get: function() { debugger; return realValue; } 
    });
})();
```

and simply run it in your browsers console.