# Chrome JavaScript Debugging: how to break when a value changes

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome

I am debugging a large JavaScript code base where, at some point, the "console" variable gets nulled when refreshing the page.

Is there a way to set a watch on console and make JavaScript break execution when that value changes (or when a condition `(console == null)` is true)?

I am using Chrome on Windows 7.

Comment: Similar question is found here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577535/break-points-on-user-defined-object-properties-in-javascript

Comment: Solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56582385/devtools-break-on-expression/56582386#56582386

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The answer below doesn't work for `window.console` because `console` (like other browser-native environment variables) is treated specially. Any attempt to assign a value to `console` only "covers up" the original value; it does not replace it. You can't detect when the `console` value changes, but you can `delete window.console` to restore the original environment-supplied value.

For other values, use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to define a custom setter for some global `window.foobar`. The setter function runs whenever `window.foobar` is assigned a new value:

```
(function() {
    var actualFoobar = window.foobar;

    Object.defineProperty(window, "foobar", {
        set: function(newValue) {
            if(newValue === null) { 
                alert("someone is clobbering foobar!"); // <-- breakpoint here!
            }

            // comment out to disallow setting window.foobar
            actualFoobar = newValue;
        },

        get: function() { return actualFoobar; }
    });

})();
```

Then, put a breakpoint in that setter function.

This approach will work for global variables or any object property (simply change `window` to the object that has the property).

Comment: perhaps it's more informative to alert/log/document.write `console.trace()`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem An excellent suggestion; I have added it. I don't know if it's strictly necessary, since the OP just wants to add a breakpoint, but it's a fine idea nevertheless.

Comment: I've not tested your suggestion in an actual script yet, but when pasting in the browser's console, it makes no difference at all, unless for when the entire console is reassigned. When reassigning `console.log` it still breaks

Comment: Right, that's intent, isn't it? From the OP: `at some point, the "console" variable gets nulled when refreshing the page.` The OP said he wanted to watch the `console` variable, not any of its member variables, so `console.log` should be freely nullable. Am I misreading the question? Or do you mean my code is causing `console.log` to somehow *not* be nullable anymore?

Comment: Indeed it was `console`, not `console.log` that was getting overwritten. Thanks for your code, that is a great way in general to catch a change to a global variable. Mysteriously, it does NOT get triggered in my case but its mere presence (the `get` method returning `actualConsole`) fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Browser-implemented functions can't be null-ed! Technically speaking.

If `window.console.log` funcion was assigned `null`, then just restore it deleting it!

```
delete console.log
```

That will do the job :)

EDIT: That's not an answer to your main question, but I think your question is comming from you searching a way to debug, so this answer basically skips the need to detect var changes.

Comment: `console` is not a function, it's an object, and it can absolutely be set to null.

Answer (score 0):

You can't touch the `console` object... never, ever. The only thing that can happen is that a `console` variable is declared in a scope/namespace, other than the global scope, hiding the global console. You can still access it using `window.console`, though. Other than that, the only things I can think of that cause this are:

- You've set the user agent in your console overrides to emulate a version of IE that doesn't support `console`
- Your code is throwing an error because of some other problem with your code
- As @alexandernst pointed out: you're overriding a property of the console object. Delete the method you're unable to access and you're fine

---

To find out where you need to look in the code [set conditional breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints) and watch a couple of expressions, and *use the **pause on uncaught exceptions** button*

Comment: I found that overwriting `console` was effectively clobbering it. `window.console` did not go back to the original console.

Comment: using `window.console` would've only worked if `console` got redefined in a scope _other_ than the global scope. If `window.console` didn't work, chances are that `delete console;` or `delete window.console` would have done the trick

Comment: This answer is very old, I know, but it makes no sense.  Just try opening your console in dev tools and: `window.console = null`.  Game over.