# console.log doesn't work sometimes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have encountered this several times, & there is no explanation for it. There was no JS errors on the site. The code is indeed being executed. Replacing them with `alert()` works just fine.

So today that happened again, so I tried to check the console object in the console object & I found some irregularities as if something has overwritten the console object.

The following screenshot is of the site (site A) where I have this problem:

http://ompldr.org/vZ256Mw/Selection_004.jpg

You see how log, warn & info are empty functions? and the console object is different from how it is on a site (site B) where console works fine (screenshot follows)?

http://ompldr.org/vZ256Mg/Selection_003.jpg

Now the code running on both the sites is exactly same. Site B is my local install and Site A is staging and I don't have anything in the code which overwrites the console object, so what could be an explanation for this behavior?

---

As per nfroidure's suggestion, I added that code in my head section before anything else and I got this: `uncaught error! (anonymous function) (anonymous function)`, second of which points to a code in another library file which has the following in it:

```
if (!("console" in window) || !("firebug" in console))
{
    var names = ["log", "debug", "info", "warn", "error", "assert", "dir", "dirxml",
    "group", "groupEnd", "time", "timeEnd", "count", "trace", "profile", "profileEnd"];

    window.console = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; ++i)
        window.console[names[i]] = function() {}
}
```

This is responsible because I think the if check is faulty. `"console" in window` will be true & `"firebug" in window` will be false for me in Chrome resulting in replacing the console methods. It should be `&&` over there, no?

**Update:** After changing the operator to `&&` it started to work on Site A, but I don't understand why it only gets triggered on one and not on another.

Comment: What code do you have included? Might some third-party code have nulled the `console`?

Comment: Is this a bug in the browser? Because you are saying it happens only sometimes.

Comment: @Bergi A lot, but when I do a grep 'console' on the project, jQuery validation plugin shows up but even that is just checking for the object before using it.

Comment: Or possibly a browser extension is fiddling with `console`? Try disabling all your extensions.

Comment: @LPD It has happened to me over a span of 2-3 years

Comment: @apsillers Tried in incognito, still the same without extension

Comment: Possibly try a debugging tactic I describe here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291814/chrome-javascript-debugging-how-to-break-when-a-value-changes/13291928#13291928

Comment: @apsillers Its unlikely but could be the case. I think if it was in the code, that should happen on my local environment too, right?

Comment: Is everything working 100% properly and the same on local as on staging?  All JS files getting included and executed exactly the same etc... ?  Is it the case that you can open the browser, visit local site and see OK console, then just change the URL to staging and see broken console?

Comment: @Treborbob yep! exactly same. I don't see anything broken in console. I observed the behavior when I tried to use `console.log`

Comment: I updated the question with some progress I had, which is actually responsible for this, can you guys check?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Site A has firebug included since console has methods that look a lot like the ones here: http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API

Comment: Sorry no, the site doesn't have firebug added to it.

Comment: …or at least [FireBug lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) called or some browser extension. Looks very much like that, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this on the top of your document :

```
<script>
(function(){
    var wc=window.console;
    delete window.console;
    window.__defineGetter__("console", function(){
        return wc;
        });

    window.__defineSetter__("console", function(val){
        throw('error!');  // Look at js stack when throwed
        });
})();
</script>
```

Comment: top as in even before `<html>` or inside `<head>` before anything else?

Comment: inside <head>. I didn't test syntax.

Comment: Try to replace :
    if (!("console" in window) || !("firebug" in console))
by
    if ((!("console" in window)) || !("firebug" in console))

Comment: yeah that made it work, but why it only gets triggered on staging (SiteA) and not on local (SiteB), any clues?

Comment: And can you edit your answer to include an explaination of the code & how you got to the point of doing that?