# Javascript break on watched expression

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to debug code with Chrome Dev Tools.

I want to find the line of code when let's say `x` became null.

I've started using the Watch Expression feature, which helps, but I still need click line by line to make the code slowly execute while keeping my eyes on the watched expression. I also have to decide each time whether to "step into" or "step over". 
I keep missing the breaking point and I have to do it all over again.

Is there a way to let the code run and automatically stop when my watched expression has changed value?

Comment: At a specific line of code, or *anywhere*? The former is possible, I'm not sure the latter is in Chrome's dev tools...

Comment: you could implement object mutators.

Comment: Anywhere - I am trying to find the line of code that turned my var to null. I'm open to other tools outside of chrome dev tools of course.

Comment: Is it possible to use a function to set x and test the new value each time and then step out or get a stack trace using an Error?

Comment: possibly a duplicate of [Chrome JavaScript Debugging: how to break when a value changes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13291814/710446)

Comment: I saw that question but because his question related to `console` all the answers were specific to `console`.

Comment: @NathanH The first paragraph of my answer explains why my solution does *not* work for `console`, but works for any other property.

Comment: The variable is not a public property but a private var. If I turned my var into a property, wouldn't it mean I need to look for every use of the var and change it to a property call? 
Also, I actually don't have easy access to the source code, I can't make changes and save my changes.