# Devtools break on expression

Tags: html, debugging, web, devtools

I would like to suspend everything when a given Javascript expression is true.

I have seen conditional breakpoints, but that doesn't work for me, because that would require setting a breakpoint somewhere first, or based on a certain criterion first, and adding an additional condition to it.

What I want instead is to be able to break anytime a given expression is true, wherever the place.

Answer (score 0):

Type the following in Devtools console:

```
setInterval(function() {
    if(<your condition>) {
        debugger;
    }
}, 10);
```

This will poll for that condition every 10 ms, and break when it is met.

You can adjust `10` to be looser if that works for you. A 10 ms frequency is already a big strain on processor.

Comment: This doesn't reveal what line of code has caused the change.