# Watch webpage for any javascript variable change in chrome or firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, developer-console

I would like to watch for any variables that change on a webpage using chrome or firefox (or any browser). Is there an extension or method to do that?

E.g. If a webpage has a few hundred variables, I would like to know when `x` or any other variable changes in value.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure this will make the code stop when the variable changes, but it's the closest thing I could find.

> The Watch Expressions tab lets you monitor the values of variables
>   over time. As the name implies, Watch Expressions aren't just limited
>   to variables. You can store any valid JavaScript expression in a Watch
>   Expression. Try it now:
>
> - Click the Watch tab.
> - Click Add Expression Add Expression.
> - Type typeof sum.
>
>   Press Enter. DevTools shows typeof sum: "string". The value to the right of the colon is the result of your Watch Expression.

[image]

Source: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/#watch-expressions

This stackoverflow question is also worth reading: [Chrome JavaScript Debugging: how to break when a value changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291814/chrome-javascript-debugging-how-to-break-when-a-value-changes)

Also: [Break on a change of variable value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910623/break-on-a-change-of-variable-value)